# Area of combination of solid objects?

Tags: geometry

i am trying to find area of a cylinder with a cone on top and bottom of it.
 -- for cylinder i used simple formula: 2*pi*r*h
-- for cone, i used 2*pi*r*l (for 2 cones)
but, what i am finding seems like just lateral surface area. Should I not add 2*pi*r^2 on it?

Comment: Those two disks are not exposed, so are not part of the surface.

Comment: Do you mean surface area?